# DotNetNuke call to wcf service to GetModule(ModuleId) fails - Objects reference null exception

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am working on DotNetNuke version 7.4.
in my Setting.ascx client side code of the module that I'm creating, I have a jquery ajax call to a wcf service which is supposed to get the module Information for the moduleId I pass to the method of the service.

When it creates new instance of ModuleCotroller, the Factory property inside the moduleController  is null.
thus trying to GetModule fails with following error:
"object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleController moduleController = new DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleController();

if (moduleController != null)
{
    var requestedModule = moduleController.GetModule(moduleid);
}
```

I have added all nesseary config info required for DotNetnuke as well as the dlls.
Can someone please guide me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but you want to use the ModuleController factory to return the instance like this:

```
var modInfo = DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleController.Instance.GetModule(moduleId, tabId, false);
```